# Optimized SIMD vector library is out performed by equivalent scalar operations?

Tags: c++, eigen, simd

I made this code to test performance of eigen additons versus plain old scalar additions.

```
int x, y;
cin >> x; cin >> y;
typedef int theType;
Array<theType, 8, 1> theArray; theArray << 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
StopWatch sw;
sw.Start();
for(int k = 0; k < y*1000000; k++){
    theArray << 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 *x; i++){
        theArray += 2;
    }
}
sw.Stop();
cout << theArray << " : " << sw.MilliSeconds() << endl;

theType f = 0;
sw.Start();
for(int k = 0; k < y*1000000; k++){
    f = f-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 80 * x; i++){
        f += 2;
    }
}
sw.Stop();
cout << f << " : " << sw.MilliSeconds();
```

I'm running that code useing g++ -O2. I set x and y with command line and use them as the upperbound in the for loops so the compiler wont optimize-out the for loop. The eigen test makes an array of 8 values, and adds a constant component wise. The scalar test just increments a scalar value, but its done 8x as much as the eigen test.

results (using x = 1, y=1):

using int as the type: 52 ms Eigen vs. 1ms scalar

using short as the type: 54 ms Eigen vs. 1ms scalar

Why is Eigen slower? I expected it to be somewhat faster because of the SIMD use in eigen. Is eigen really this slow, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 80 * x; i++){
    f += 2;
}
```

is optimized away by compiler. Compiling on VC++ for x86 the whole loop folds into one single assembly instruction:

```
lea esi, DWORD PTR [esi+ecx*2]
```

Where `ecx` is value of 80*x, and `esi` is the value of `f` variable.

You will need some way to disable loop optimizations. In addition to this, performing 8 operations on single scalar is always faster than one operation on array of 8 elements, so I suggest converting your `f` variable into array `f[8]`, to achieve parity with vector code. Once you do this, you will find the Eigen noticeably faster than non-vectorized code.

Comment: "performing 8 operations on single scalar is always faster than one operation on array of 8 elements"... that's true only if they can be optimized into fewer operations (such as 8 adds into a multiply and add).  For example, comparing a scalar against 8 constants is far slower than comparing a SIMD vector of 8 elements against one constant.